# Cover letter - fancy structure

Tags: letters, letterhead

Honestly,I don't know where to start in order to replicate the structure in the image below, for my cover letter. The end result should look like the cover letter at [this webpage](https://www.boldstationery.com/listing/219389985/modern-resume-template-05-with-matching).

Here is a MWE, which is my default document for cover letters, although I am quite sure it does not fit my needs this time.

Appreciate any hint to get started right.

```
\documentclass[symbolicnames]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{blindtext} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{John Smith}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{123 City\\City\\Country}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{(000) 111-1111}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{john@smith.com}
\setkomavar{signature}{John Smith}
\setkomavar{subject}{Cover Letter}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
    \centering{\Huge\scshape\usekomavar{fromname}\par%
%   \vspace{1em}%<- apply space as needed
}%
    {\Large\scshape Cover Letter\par}%
}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\centering
{%
\renewcommand{\\}{~{\large\textperiodcentered}~}%
\usekomavar{fromaddress}%
}\\%
\usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}\quad\usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{%
Hiring Company\\%
123 Street\\%
12345 City, State%
}

\opening{Dear Recruiter,}
\blindtext[2]

\blindtext

\blindtext[3]
\closing{Best,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: this structure]

Answer (score 2):

This answer does not  reproduce your design exactly, but it comes close enough. It also makes use of pandoc instead of pure LaTeX, but can serve as a start.

The resulting page will look like the following:

[image]

It only needs three steps, following instructions from the [source](https://lf-araujo.github.io/posts/zletter) where you can also find a [CV](https://lf-araujo.github.io/posts/Yet-Another-CV) automation tool, as well as a [report](https://lf-araujo.github.io/2017/11/10/tuftish.html) theme.

First step, clone the GitHub repo with:

```
git clone https://github.com/lf-araujo/pandoc-letter.git
```

Second step, cd into the `/style` directory and edit the `letterhead.md` file to your needs.

Third step, cd into the `/source` directory and edit your `letter.md` file.

Finally, build the whole thing with `make` and **Bang!**

This solution uses a building Makefile for pandoc that supports themes and allows to ease writing workflow using any text editor that allows the user to configure building instructions. An explanation of the underlying building system can be found [here](https://lf-araujo.github.io/2017/08/14/mmv1.html).